# How can I use an updated dictionary from main() function in another function?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is in the main function and I want to use it in another function to present the data in a tabular format.
I had created the dictionary in a function as follows:

```
def file_reader():
        config_dict = {}
        newDict = {}
        configParser = configparser.ConfigParser()

        configParser.read('config.ini')
        for section in configParser.sections():
                for k,v in configParser.items(section):
                        config_dict[k] = v
                config_dict = dict(configParser.items('SectionTwo'))
                rev_dict = dict(map(reversed, configParser.items('SectionOne')))
                for v in rev_dict:
                        newDict[k] = rev_dict[v]
                list_vals = list(config_dict.values())
                list_keys = list(config_dict.keys())
                return rev_dict, newDict
```

I then used the dictionary created in the above function in main function as follows:

```
def main():
rev_dict, newDict = file_reader()
parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', help='start script', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

elif args.start:
                for k,v in rev_dict.items():
                        print("\nTestcase:" + v + "\n");print(v, "=", k);print("\n");time.sleep(5);
                        proc = sp.call([k], shell=True);time.sleep(5);
                        print('Process ID is:', os.getpid())
                        if proc != 0:
                                if proc < 0:
                                        print("\nKilled by signal!\n", -proc)
                                else:
                                        print("\nFailed with return code: ", proc)
                                        newDict[v] = 'Fail'
                                        print(json.dumps(dic, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
                        else:
                                print("\nOK\n")
                                newDict[v] = 'Pass';
                                print(json.dumps(dic, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
                                sipResponse(args.ip)
```

I had then created a function called read_file() where I want to generate a report and use the updated dictionary named **newDict** from main function.

```
def read_file():
        rev_dict = file_reader()
        shutil.copy("logfile.log", "file.txt")
        f = open("file.txt", "r+")
        headers = ['Testcase', 'Path']
        data = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in rev_dict.items()])
        f.write(tabulate(data, headers=headers, tablefmt="grid"))
        f.close()
        sys.exit(0)
```

Can someone please guide?

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce an argument to the `read_file` function:

```
def read_file(new_dict):
```

Then in `main` when you want to call the new function, call `read_file(newDict)`. Notice how the argument name in the function is `new_dict`, thus showing that the two names are actually different.

Thus main might look something like this, with other code removed for simplicity: just add a call to the other method.

```
def main():
    rev_dict, newDict = file_reader()
    read_file(newDict)
```

Comment: How can I use the dictionary from main() in any other function?